# Specific Parts of ImageView clickable

Tags: android, layout, imageview, imagemap

What are some ideas about having an ImageView that takes up the whole screen and making only parts of it clickable? I was thinking that I could extend the ImageView class and override its ontouch method which would allow me to detect touches based on an x and y. The only problem I can see with this is on different resolutions the touches might not map to the correct areas. I suppose I could then detect the resolution and figure out some way to map the x and y to the correct areas. I feel like there must be an easier way though. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating transparent views with your desired click listeners on top of the ImageView using a RelativeLayout.  You can use the xml to place those "hotspots" where you would like them relative to your image and define the layout so the "hotspot" view scale properly along with the image when displayed on different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am a big fan of the RelativeLayout but I didn't think about it in this case haha. It worked great though, I was able to use it on both my phone and tablet and the "hotspots" stayed the same. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If the 'hotspot' shapes are not too complex, you could dynamically split the image, setup individual clicklisteners and re-merge the drawables in a way for them to appear contiguous. I do like Gregg's method more though.